# Cannot find module './driver'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when i run my project in nodejs i get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
```

please someone can help me!

Comment: Can you add more details like in which line you are getting error?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is npm related problem. Try to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`.
If above solution doesn't work for you, try to use `yarn` rather than `npm`, which I did when I had this problem.